# move all files in a folder and all it's subfolders into one big folder - windows xp

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, file-copying

I have a folder c:\downloads\ffme and inside it there are loads of subfolders with various amounts of files in each of them.

I want to consolidate all those individual files into one big folder, removing them from their subfolders on the way. I want to end up with a folder with loads of files in it, but no subfolders. How can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way would be w/o a cmd... just open the folder in Windows Explorer and search for `*.*`, then select everything except the subfolders and drag/drop or cut/paste to the desired location.

Comment: Or you can search for `*.?*` to match only file names (No folders). I hope it helps

Comment: Brilliant.  The tip from @OuldAbba worked great as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use standard file recursion but rather than maintaining a directory structure, move the final file, unless of course the name already exists, then you would need to allow for renaming so that the file is maybe prepended with a directory name to maintain the unique filenames.

Have you done any form of recursive code?

Comment: nope, haven't a clue what you are talking about unfortunately :( Is it something easy? It doesn't sound like it

Comment: I should clarify, I'm a total newb. I was hoping there would be a command I could type into cmd in windows and it would do the job. But I've not really used cmd before