# Move multiple files from multiple folders to one folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, move

I am looking for a .bat file that can look inside multiple folders that contain sub-folders that are named the same and move their contents to a specified folder.

Folder Structure:
**Main_folder**

1. MainTextures_folder
2. Props_folder
   --model1_subfolder
   ------Textures_subfolder
          ----------*image files*
   --model2_subfolder
       -------Textures_subfolder
          ----------*image files*
    --model3_subfolder
       -------Textures_subfolder
          ----------*image files*
    --model4_subfolder
       -------Textures_subfolder
          ----------*image files*

I need all image files moved from their Textures_subfolder to the MainTextures_folder.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258908/move-all-files-in-a-folder-and-all-its-subfolders-into-one-big-folder-windows

Comment: the problem i have with this solution (which is a good one) is that there is a corresponding .meta file with each file within the entire folder structure.  i do need to move the .meta files that correspond to the image files, but not the model files.  therefore, if i add .meta to the search it will find files that i do not want to move (i.e. the .meta files for the models)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expects model* folders under the props folder, and that each model* folder has a textures folder.  The MainTextures folder is in the Main_folder.

It's untested and should move all files from each textures folder into the MainTextures folder.

```
@echo off
pushd "Main_folder\Props"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir model* /b /ad') do (
move /-y "%%a\textures\*.*" "..\MainTextures"
)
popd
```

Comment: that worked great!!! now...you have "('dir model* /b /ad')", what needs to be written if each model folder has a unique name (model1 = truck_model, model2 = plane_model, etc)?

Comment: If each folder under Props is a model folder then remove `model*` altogether.

Comment: You're welcome.  You can accept the answer, and others in future will know that it's worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /r "Props_folder" %%x in (*.jpg *.png *.bmp *.whatever) move "%%~fx" "MainTextures_folder"
```

This code will overwrite all existing files.

Comment: this is not working for me.  i copied the code and pasted it into a txt document and changed it to a bat file.  put the file inside the main folder and ran it.  nothing happened.